# Measuring the Kc of equilibrium between NO2 and N2O4

Tags: equilibrium, experimental-chemistry, concentration

I'm trying to measure the $K_c$ of the equilibrium reaction

$$\ce{2 NO2 (g) <=> N2O4 (g)}$$

in different temperatures. How would I do this do this in a normal school laboratory? I was thinking of shining (laser) light through a test tube that contained $\ce{NO2 (g)}$ and looking at the intensity of light emitted. $\ce{NO2 (g)}$ is dark-reddish brown and $\ce{N2O4 (g)}$ is colorless. That means that the more to the right the equation is, the more light will be emitted.

However, I don't think this would give me accurate values for $K_c$. Are there any other methods that I could use to do this which preferably don't require advanced equipment (which I don't have)?

Comment: Nice question! You've got me thinking.  So you know, I took the LaTeX out of the title because it makes things look messy in searches.

Comment: @Brian Oh, thanks! I didn't realize that, but it makes sense. I'll keep that in mind for the future! Also, thanks for correcting the equation and tags – that was a silly mistake on my part :)

Comment: No prob - welcome to the site!

Comment: If you have an equipment, that allows you to measure pressure change during reaction, you can easily compute partial pressures and equilibrium constant.

Comment: @VadimShkaberda wow, that's a great idea! I can measure pressure, and I probably could use these calculate that and try to find $K_c$ that way. I'll look into that!

Comment: Skel, can you add a summary of what equipment you *do* have available? Otherwise, it's really hard to narrow down possible approaches.

Comment: I agree with @Brian, it is really not possible to answer this without the knowledge of your equipment. Also note, that you are probably trying to measure $K_p$ (with partial pressures) as you have gasses.

Comment: @Brian hey! Actually, I decided to try to use a pressure meter that we have, but it unfortunately wasn't accurate enough (the pressure seemed to fluctuate the whole time). I wanted to use the partial pressures method, but maybe I just don't have equipment accurate enough for it. That's why I decided to try another experiment, like perhaps finding the solubility curve of a certain substance in a certain solvent. If you want me to, though, I can list the equipment that I have! I'm really on the fence with the Kc experiment :)

Comment: Skel, it's up to you if you still want an answer to the question..! Just edit the list of equipment into the question, and it'll trigger a reopen vote.

Comment: @hBy2Py Thanks! I decided not to, though. But thanks for helping! :)